# how i can use .svg image for native script spash screen, backgrounds and all icons,buttons?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I want to remove the .png files that I used for my native script android app and add .svg files instead of those.I want to use svg images for spash screen ,backgrounds and all icons,buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SVG within your app, you must use [nativescript-svg](https://github.com/peoplewareDo/nativescript-svg) plugin.

To use SVG in your splash screen, you will have to update `splash_screen.xml` from `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi`.

You may replace the default `item` with something like below

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/mysvg" android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png